# SELECT result as parameter in user defined table-parameter function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, common-table-expression, create-table

I need to pass `SELECT` result as parameter of user defined table-parameter function (returning table):

```
CREATE FUNCTION
...

CREATE TABLE cities
(
    ID int identity not null primary key,
    name varchar(40) unique
)

SELECT ID as startID,FUNCTION( SELECT name FROM cities ) FROM cities WHERE ID=1
```

Function is intended to `SELECT` city with `ID=1` and result of `FUNCTION` when parameter is selection of all cities. **I need to do it without assigning selection to a variable because I am using this statement inside of CTE** where variable can not be assigned (if they can be please tell me :) but it did not work in my case)

Comment: Hello :) I have tried to execute above statement, but it rejected my code because it must have been built-in function. I have also tried to INNER JOIN with TABLE variable returned from function - it worked, but not in CTE. The problem was that in a CTE it did not allow to pass selection into a function as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all evidence, that is impossible.

The example in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) shows only one way of using table-valued parameters in a Transact-SQL batch, which may already imply that there is no other method. As you can see, it shows that you need to declare and populate a table-valued variable of the same user-defined type as the parameter in your routine, then pass that variable as an argument.

If that is not enough, I believe the following passage from the article can serve as an explanation of why you need to use a variable:

> Transact-SQL passes table-valued parameters to routines **by reference** to avoid making a copy of the input data.

So, under the covers, your function would not exactly be accepting a *set* but only a *reference* to it. You would need to create that reference in your script, and that is what declaring a table-valued variable would be for.

Then there is [this (closed) Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/586878/use-a-query-in-function-instead-of-table-valued-parameter).

You will probably have to revisit your design if you want/need to avoid variable declaration. If you need help with that, please post a question elaborating on what your query is doing so that a proper alternative could be found.

Answer (score 0):

Tried APPLY?

```
SELECT c.ID, f.Name
FROM cities c
CROSS APPLY dbo.my_function(c.ID) f
```

Comment: Their function is accepting a *table*, not a single scalar value, so this is not a good alternative.

Comment: Besides, their function is scalar and you are showing a syntax for calling a table-valued function.

Comment: @AndriyM just to clarify `table valued function` does not imply you pass a table as a parameter to the function, but rather you `GET a table` as a return value, afaik both scalar and table valued functions can take tables as parameters

Comment: @DrCopyPaste: Yes, OP's is a scalar-valued function with a table-valued parameter, and the query in this answer is calling a table-valued function with a scalar-valued parameter. That difference is the issue I have with this answer.

Comment: @AndriyM Ah good we cleared that up, I admit I got confused :)